# Function to Generate Multiple htmlTables using Purrr::map

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(htmlTable)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmosaic) for "happy" dataset
```

I want to create a function that creates frequency tables for all the categorical variables in a dataset and then generate htmlTables for each one. However, by using purrr::map, the tables are in a list. How do I generate the tables using htmlTable? Or any better package that generates similar tables for publication? I suppose I need to split the list or use additional purrr::map functions? Help would be appreciated...

```
Something like this...


FUN<-function(data){
TAB<-happy%>%select_if(is.factor)%>%
map(table)
TABLES<-htmlTable(TAB)
return(TABLES)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a `tibble` to store the arguments to the function as well as the resulting HTML strings:

**Edit:** added new column (percent)

```r
library(ggmosaic) 
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse) 
library(htmlTable)
library(magrittr) 
library(scales)

data(happy)

# Use a subset of `happy` for the example
h <- happy %>% as_tibble %>% sample_n(100)

# create the function
make_html_table <- function(data, .name, .col_names) {
  data %>% 
    table %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    set_colnames(.col_names) %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    mutate(percent = scales::percent(count/sum(count))) %>%  # add the percent column
    htmlTable(caption = .name)
}

# Apply the function and store the results in a tibble
tbl <- 
    h %>% 
    select_if(is.factor) %>% 
    { tibble(NAME = names(.), 
             data = map(., ~.x)) } %>% 
    mutate(TABLE = map2(.x = data, 
                        .y = NAME, 
                        .f = make_html_table, 
                        .col_names = c("levels", "count")))

# Check out the tables in the Viewer Pane (if you're using RStudio)
tbl %>% extract2("TABLE") %>% map(htmlTableWidget)
#> $happy
#> 
#> $sex
#> 
#> $marital
#> 
#> $degree
#> 
#> $finrela
#> 
#> $health
```

Here's a screenshot of the one of the tables this creates:

[image: html table]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want, but just a few things. One, I don't seem to have htmlTableWidget? I tried doing tbl%>%extract2%>%("TABLE")%>%map(htmlTable) and it only shows the html table for health, which is the last of the list. Also, can I use tidyr::unnest instead of extract2?

Comment: For the "store the results in a Tibble" part, what is the purpose of the { } in this code? I tried it without, and it says that "each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list". I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: Finally, is there a way to add percentage into the make_html_table function? It would be great to have both a count and percentage column. Percentages are what I'm after most! I have another question posted about that too lol

Comment: htmlTableWidget is a function in the htmlTable package (v1.9)
unnest is for expanding nested data frames, which isn't necessary in this case

Comment: the { } prevents the left side of the %>% from being automatically passed as the first argument to the right side of the %>%

Comment: I added the percent column - pretty straightforward stuff if you're familiar with dplyr::mutate (if you aren't, I strongly advise you check it out)

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Can you elaborate a little more on the { } and why it was necessary in this case? I'm only familiar with the brackets for wrapping functions, so I'm curious to know why it's needed...why shouldn't the left side of the %>% be automatically piped to the right side?

Comment: The left side gets piped to the right side, but *not to the first argument* - you can read more about that here: https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/pt00_gotchas.html

Comment: It was necessary in this example because both of the arguments in tibble() needed to use the ., not just the first argument.

Comment: But even more importantly, tibble() expects a vector or a list, not a dataframe (hence the error you encountered), so the use of { } allows us to pass the right type of objects to tibble()